# ERC20: mint to the zero address exception when trying to buy my own ERC20 token (based on OpenZeppelin) from my own simple DEX

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, decentralized-applications

I have implemented my own ERC20 token (based on OpenZeppelin's implementation). I created a supply for my token and used that supply to create a very simple decentralized exchange (DEX) based on [this guide](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/tutorials/transfers-and-approval-of-erc-20-tokens-from-a-solidity-smart-contract/). I do not understand why I keep getting the `ERC20: mint to the zero address exception` even when I comment out the part of the code which causes it. I made sure that I ran `truffle migrate --reset` after I changed my contract. I also restarted Ganache, then re-compiled and migrated all the contracts again to no avail.

Here's the code for my ERC20 token (it's the same as the OpenZeppelin implementation) `MyCoin.sol`:

```
/*
    Taken from https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol
*/

// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
// OpenZeppelin Contracts v4.3.2 (token/ERC20/ERC20.sol)

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "./IERC20.sol";
import "./extensions/IERC20Metadata.sol";
import "./utils/Context.sol";

/**
 * @dev Implementation of the {IERC20} interface.
 *
 * This implementation is agnostic to the way tokens are created. This means
 * that a supply mechanism has to be added in a derived contract using {_mint}.
 * For a generic mechanism see {ERC20PresetMinterPauser}.
 *
 * TIP: For a detailed writeup see our guide
 * https://forum.zeppelin.solutions/t/how-to-implement-erc20-supply-mechanisms/226[How
 * to implement supply mechanisms].
 *
 * We have followed general OpenZeppelin Contracts guidelines: functions revert
 * instead returning `false` on failure. This behavior is nonetheless
 * conventional and does not conflict with the expectations of ERC20
 * applications.
 *
 * Additionally, an {Approval} event is emitted on calls to {transferFrom}.
 * This allows applications to reconstruct the allowance for all accounts just
 * by listening to said events. Other implementations of the EIP may not emit
 * these events, as it isn't required by the specification.
 *
 * Finally, the non-standard {decreaseAllowance} and {increaseAllowance}
 * functions have been added to mitigate the well-known issues around setting
 * allowances. See {IERC20-approve}.
 */
contract MyCoin is Context, IERC20, IERC20Metadata {
    mapping(address => uint256) private _balances;

    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint256)) private _allowances;

    uint256 private _totalSupply;

    string private _name;
    string private _symbol;

    /**
     * @dev Sets the values for {name} and {symbol}.
     *
     * The default value of {decimals} is 18. To select a different value for
     * {decimals} you should overload it.
     *
     * All two of these values are immutable: they can only be set once during
     * construction.
     */
    constructor(string memory name_, string memory symbol_) {
        _name = name_;
        _symbol = symbol_;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Returns the name of the token.
     */
    function name() public view virtual override returns (string memory) {
        return _name;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Returns the symbol of the token, usually a shorter version of the
     * name.
     */
    function symbol() public view virtual override returns (string memory) {
        return _symbol;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Returns the number of decimals used to get its user representation.
     * For example, if `decimals` equals `2`, a balance of `505` tokens should
     * be displayed to a user as `5.05` (`505 / 10 ** 2`).
     *
     * Tokens usually opt for a value of 18, imitating the relationship between
     * Ether and Wei. This is the value {ERC20} uses, unless this function is
     * overridden;
     *
     * NOTE: This information is only used for _display_ purposes: it in
     * no way affects any of the arithmetic of the contract, including
     * {IERC20-balanceOf} and {IERC20-transfer}.
     */
    function decimals() public view virtual override returns (uint8) {
        return 18;
    }

    /**
     * @dev See {IERC20-totalSupply}.
     */
    function totalSupply() public view virtual override returns (uint256) {
        return _totalSupply;
    }

    /**
     * @dev See {IERC20-balanceOf}.
     */
    function balanceOf(address account) public view virtual override returns (uint256) {
        return _balances[account];
    }

    /**
     * @dev See {IERC20-transfer}.
     *
     * Requirements:
     *
     * - `recipient` cannot be the zero address.
     * - the caller must have a balance of at least `amount`.
     */
    function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) public virtual override returns (bool) {
        _transfer(_msgSender(), recipient, amount);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * @dev See {IERC20-allowance}.
     */
    function allowance(address owner, address spender) public view virtual override returns (uint256) {
        return _allowances[owner][spender];
    }

    /**
     * @dev See {IERC20-approve}.
     *
     * Requirements:
     *
     * - `spender` cannot be the zero address.
     */
    function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) public virtual override returns (bool) {
        _approve(_msgSender(), spender, amount);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * @dev See {IERC20-transferFrom}.
     *
     * Emits an {Approval} event indicating the updated allowance. This is not
     * required by the EIP. See the note at the beginning of {ERC20}.
     *
     * Requirements:
     *
     * - `sender` and `recipient` cannot be the zero address.
     * - `sender` must have a balance of at least `amount`.
     * - the caller must have allowance for ``sender``'s tokens of at least
     * `amount`.
     */
    function transferFrom(
        address sender,
        address recipient,
        uint256 amount
    ) public virtual override returns (bool) {
        _transfer(sender, recipient, amount);

        uint256 currentAllowance = _allowances[sender][_msgSender()];
        require(currentAllowance >= amount, "ERC20: transfer amount exceeds allowance");
        unchecked {
            _approve(sender, _msgSender(), currentAllowance - amount);
        }

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Atomically increases the allowance granted to `spender` by the caller.
     *
     * This is an alternative to {approve} that can be used as a mitigation for
     * problems described in {IERC20-approve}.
     *
     * Emits an {Approval} event indicating the updated allowance.
     *
     * Requirements:
     *
     * - `spender` cannot be the zero address.
     */
    function increaseAllowance(address spender, uint256 addedValue) public virtual returns (bool) {
        _approve(_msgSender(), spender, _allowances[_msgSender()][spender] + addedValue);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Atomically decreases the allowance granted to `spender` by the caller.
     *
     * This is an alternative to {approve} that can be used as a mitigation for
     * problems described in {IERC20-approve}.
     *
     * Emits an {Approval} event indicating the updated allowance.
     *
     * Requirements:
     *
     * - `spender` cannot be the zero address.
     * - `spender` must have allowance for the caller of at least
     * `subtractedValue`.
     */
    function decreaseAllowance(address spender, uint256 subtractedValue) public virtual returns (bool) {
        uint256 currentAllowance = _allowances[_msgSender()][spender];
        require(currentAllowance >= subtractedValue, "ERC20: decreased allowance below zero");
        unchecked {
            _approve(_msgSender(), spender, currentAllowance - subtractedValue);
        }

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Moves `amount` of tokens from `sender` to `recipient`.
     *
     * This internal function is equivalent to {transfer}, and can be used to
     * e.g. implement automatic token fees, slashing mechanisms, etc.
     *
     * Emits a {Transfer} event.
     *
     * Requirements:
     *
     * - `sender` cannot be the zero address.
     * - `recipient` cannot be the zero address.
     * - `sender` must have a balance of at least `amount`.
     */
    function _transfer(
        address sender,
        address recipient,
        uint256 amount
    ) internal virtual {
        require(sender != address(0), "ERC20: transfer from the zero address");
        require(recipient != address(0), "ERC20: transfer to the zero address");

        _beforeTokenTransfer(sender, recipient, amount);

        uint256 senderBalance = _balances[sender];
        require(senderBalance >= amount, "ERC20: transfer amount exceeds balance");
        unchecked {
            _balances[sender] = senderBalance - amount;
        }
        _balances[recipient] += amount;

        emit Transfer(sender, recipient, amount);

        _afterTokenTransfer(sender, recipient, amount);
    }

    /** @dev Creates `amount` tokens and assigns them to `account`, increasing
     * the total supply.
     *
     * Emits a {Transfer} event with `from` set to the zero address.
     *
     * Requirements:
     *
     * - `account` cannot be the zero address.
     */
    function _mint(address account, uint256 amount) internal virtual {
        // require(account != address(0), "ERC20: mint to the zero address"); // this is commented out for development purposes; TODO: uncomment this in production

        _beforeTokenTransfer(address(0), account, amount);

        _totalSupply += amount;
        _balances[account] += amount;
        emit Transfer(address(0), account, amount);

        _afterTokenTransfer(address(0), account, amount);
    }

    /**
     * @dev Destroys `amount` tokens from `account`, reducing the
     * total supply.
     *
     * Emits a {Transfer} event with `to` set to the zero address.
     *
     * Requirements:
     *
     * - `account` cannot be the zero address.
     * - `account` must have at least `amount` tokens.
     */
    function _burn(address account, uint256 amount) internal virtual {
        require(account != address(0), "ERC20: burn from the zero address");

        _beforeTokenTransfer(account, address(0), amount);

        uint256 accountBalance = _balances[account];
        require(accountBalance >= amount, "ERC20: burn amount exceeds balance");
        unchecked {
            _balances[account] = accountBalance - amount;
        }
        _totalSupply -= amount;

        emit Transfer(account, address(0), amount);

        _afterTokenTransfer(account, address(0), amount);
    }

    /**
     * @dev Sets `amount` as the allowance of `spender` over the `owner` s tokens.
     *
     * This internal function is equivalent to `approve`, and can be used to
     * e.g. set automatic allowances for certain subsystems, etc.
     *
     * Emits an {Approval} event.
     *
     * Requirements:
     *
     * - `owner` cannot be the zero address.
     * - `spender` cannot be the zero address.
     */
    function _approve(
        address owner,
        address spender,
        uint256 amount
    ) internal virtual {
        require(owner != address(0), "ERC20: approve from the zero address");
        require(spender != address(0), "ERC20: approve to the zero address");

        _allowances[owner][spender] = amount;
        emit Approval(owner, spender, amount);
    }

    /**
     * @dev Hook that is called before any transfer of tokens. This includes
     * minting and burning.
     *
     * Calling conditions:
     *
     * - when `from` and `to` are both non-zero, `amount` of ``from``'s tokens
     * will be transferred to `to`.
     * - when `from` is zero, `amount` tokens will be minted for `to`.
     * - when `to` is zero, `amount` of ``from``'s tokens will be burned.
     * - `from` and `to` are never both zero.
     *
     * To learn more about hooks, head to xref:ROOT:extending-contracts.adoc#using-hooks[Using Hooks].
     */
    function _beforeTokenTransfer(
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256 amount
    ) internal virtual {}

    /**
     * @dev Hook that is called after any transfer of tokens. This includes
     * minting and burning.
     *
     * Calling conditions:
     *
     * - when `from` and `to` are both non-zero, `amount` of ``from``'s tokens
     * has been transferred to `to`.
     * - when `from` is zero, `amount` tokens have been minted for `to`.
     * - when `to` is zero, `amount` of ``from``'s tokens have been burned.
     * - `from` and `to` are never both zero.
     *
     * To learn more about hooks, head to xref:ROOT:extending-contracts.adoc#using-hooks[Using Hooks].
     */
    function _afterTokenTransfer(
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256 amount
    ) internal virtual {}
}
```

Notice how I commented out the `require` line in `_mint`.

Here's the code for `MyCoinSupply.sol`:

```
/*
    Adapted from from https://forum.openzeppelin.com/t/how-to-implement-erc20-supply-mechanisms/226
*/

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "./MyCoin.sol";

contract MyCoinSupply is MyCoin("MyCoin", "MyC") // MyCoin is ERC20
{
    constructor() public // gives 1000 tokens to the owner
    {
        _mint(msg.sender, 1000);
    }

    function _mintMinerReward() internal // gives 20 tokens to the miner
    {
        _mint(block.coinbase, 20);
    }

    function _transfer(address from, address to, uint256 value) override internal
    {
        _mintMinerReward();
        super._transfer(from, to, value);
    }
}
```

and here's the code for `MyCoinDEX.sol`:

```
/*
    Adapted from https://ethereum.org/en/developers/tutorials/transfers-and-approval-of-erc-20-tokens-from-a-solidity-smart-contract/

    I didn't try to code my own DEX from scratch because I wasn't familiar with token to Ether conversion dynamics,
    so I thought a better idea would be to modify existing solutions.
*/

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "./IERC20.sol";
import "./MyCoinSupply.sol";

contract MyCoinDEX
{
    IERC20 public token;

    event Bought(uint256 amount);
    event Sold(uint256 amount);

    constructor() public
    {
        token = new MyCoinSupply();
    }

    function showSender() public view returns (address) // for debugging purposes
    {
        return (msg.sender);
    }

    function buy() payable public // send ether and get tokens in exchange; 1 token == 1 ether
    {
      uint256 amountTobuy = msg.value;
      uint256 dexBalance = token.balanceOf(address(this));
      require(amountTobuy > 0, "You need to send some ether");
      require(amountTobuy <= dexBalance, "Not enough tokens in the reserve");
      token.transfer(msg.sender, amountTobuy);
      emit Bought(amountTobuy);
    }

    function sell(uint256 amount) public // send tokens to get ether back
    {
      require(amount > 0, "You need to sell at least some tokens");
      uint256 allowance = token.allowance(msg.sender, address(this));
      require(allowance >= amount, "Check the token allowance");
      token.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount);
      payable(msg.sender).transfer(amount);
      emit Sold(amount);
    }

}
```

Here's how I interact with the contract:

```
truffle(development)> let instance = await MyCoinDEX.deployed()
undefined
truffle(development)> instance.buy({value: 1})
Uncaught:
Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert ERC20: mint to the zero address -- Reason given: ERC20: mint to the zero address.
    at evalmachine.<anonymous>
    at sigintHandlersWrap (node:vm:268:12)
    at Script.runInContext (node:vm:137:14)
    at runScript (/home/john/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/console.js:364:1)
    at Console.interpret (/home/john/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/console.js:379:1)
    at bound (node:domain:421:15)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (node:domain:432:12)
    at REPLServer.onLine (node:repl:889:10)
    at REPLServer.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at REPLServer.emit (node:domain:475:12)
    at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (node:readline:487:10)
    at REPLServer.Interface._line (node:readline:864:8)
    at REPLServer.Interface._ttyWrite (node:readline:1216:14)
    at REPLServer.self._ttyWrite (node:repl:984:9) {
  data: {
    '0xae1903eb07c1e80c3b8ddef277d81496afdfa9a599e5be75d3234ecf19003078': {
      error: 'revert',
      program_counter: 663,
      return: '0x08c379a00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001f45524332303a206d696e7420746f20746865207a65726f206164647265737300',
      reason: 'ERC20: mint to the zero address'
    },
    stack: 'RuntimeError: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert ERC20: mint to the zero address\n' +
      '    at Function.RuntimeError.fromResults (/tmp/.mount_ganach2RAdVJ/resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache-core/lib/utils/runtimeerror.js:94:13)\n' +
      '    at BlockchainDouble.processBlock (/tmp/.mount_ganach2RAdVJ/resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache-core/lib/blockchain_double.js:627:24)\n' +
      '    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)\n' +
      '    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)',
    name: 'RuntimeError'
  },
  reason: 'ERC20: mint to the zero address',
  hijackedStack: 'Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert ERC20: mint to the zero address -- Reason given: ERC20: mint to the zero address.\n' +
    '    at Object.ErrorResponse (/home/john/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/web3-core-helpers/lib/errors.js:28:1)\n' +
    '    at /home/john/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/web3/node_modules/web3-core-requestmanager/lib/index.js:302:1\n' +
    '    at /home/john/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/provider/wrapper.js:107:1\n' +
    '    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (/home/john/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/web3/node_modules/web3-providers-http/lib/index.js:98:1)\n' +
    '    at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (/home/john/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request-event-target.js:34:1)\n' +
    '    at XMLHttpRequest.exports.modules.996763.XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (/home/john/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js:208:1)\n' +
    '    at XMLHttpRequest.exports.modules.996763.XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (/home/john/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js:318:1)\n' +
    '    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/john/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js:289:47)\n' +
    '    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:402:35)\n' +
    '    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:domain:537:15)\n' +
    '    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1343:12)\n' +
    '    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)'
}
```

I tested the hypothesis that msg.sender might be 0, but it isn't, because:

```
truffle(development)> instance.showSender()
'0x9292726A62cAeE7CDCd573ca02F11FE03306d950'
```

and even if it was, I commented out the code that throws the specific exception I get.

**Can somebody take a look and tell me what is going on here?** I'm bamboozled by this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you have to remove the `build/` folder then compile it again to make a fresh compile and deploy.

Second, I think the problem of error when calling `buy()` function is, you create an instant of your token in contract constructor, I don't do that in my  projects. I deploy the token separately, then pass it address to the constructor, like this:

```
constructor(address _tokenAddress) public {
  token = IERC20(_tokenAddress);
}
```